# Rename downloaded file from FTP server and upload to separate FTP server using the renamed file

Tags: c#, ftp

So I have my FTP program working great with static file names for the download and upload portions.  Now management has asked that the program be able to rename the downloaded file and append the date to the file in MMdd format and then up load that file to the ftp server.

I think I have the code correct for the renaming part of the process here

```
//Generate name for download file
string filePath = @"c:\";
string fileName = Path.Combine(filePath,string.Format("PMP{MMdd}.txt", DateTime.Now));
```

My question is how do I pass that variable over to the upload portion of the program.

This is how I have the class defined

```
public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
```

And this is how I'm passing the static file names over to the class

```
/* Upload a File */
UploadftpClient.upload("testup.txt", @"c:\testup.txt");
```

I built the program using the code found here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class

Programming isn't my strong suit and I'm stumped as to how to accomplish what I need to do here.

Comment: Can you change the name of the file on disc programmatically and then upload the new filename?

Comment: You just need to do: `UploadftpClient.upload("testup.txt", fileName);` or is it the other way 'round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
UploadftpClient.upload(Path.GetFileName(localfile), localfile);
```

EDIT: The following line should replace the one you are using

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(filePath, "PMP" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMdd") + ".txt");
```

Comment: I tried that out and the program compiled without an issue but when I ran it I got the following error


    Unahandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: I misunderstood your problem, I updated my answer with a fix for the error you are getting. The error you are getting is from the way you are parsing the datetime object to a string.